# Flutter; Show the page once

Tags: flutter

Hi I want the user make a choice when the application is first opened. After that, I don't want user to see this page every time enters the application. (If user wants, user can switch to the page from the drawer menu.)
What should i do to do this?(I already have a splash screen in my application. This is a separate page)

Answer (score 1):

We can utilize `SharedPreferences` package.

After user visits the BaseScreen page, we have to write 'log', 'note', or 'tracenote', locally in the device.

There are already package options, e.g, `SQFlite`, `Hive`, but personally I recommend `Shared Preferences` package.

Below I showed you the basic code so you can get the **idea**.

### Code

```dart
class BaseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BaseScreenState createState() => _BaseScreenState();
}

class _BaseScreenState extends State<BaseScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    navigateToRealAppScreen();
  }

  void navigateToLastPage() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String isOpened = prefs.getString('first_screen_already_opened');
    
    // Need to push to another screen, if already opened
    if (lastRoute == 'true') {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/realAppScreen');
    }
  }
```